# Setting Notification using AlarmManager by passing calendar.getTimeInMillis(),triggers notification instantly not at the time intended

Tags: android, notifications, calendar, alarm

I have followed the following link https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html.

RTC examples first one, to set an alarm for a specific time on all days. Even after following the same code, the alarm is not triggered at the time it is suppose to get triggered. Instead the `notification` gets triggered immediately after setting the time which is done with the help of a time picker. Following is my code snippet,

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)     getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent intentalarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,4);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intentalarm);
```

Instead of `setRepeating` I also tried `setInexactRepeating` but there was no luck.I would also like to add that when I changed the

`calendar.getTimeInMillis()` and used `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 120 * 1000` the alarm triggered exactly after 2 minutes from the time it was set.

But when `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` is being used the intended working does not happen instead immediate triggering occurs.

Would be indeed very helpful if anyone can help me out find a solution.Only for a note, I could learn if alarm is set before current device time the alarm would be triggered immediately but that is not the case here.

`NotificationReceiver.class` is working fine as it is generated and appears on the title. But the time it appears is the cause of concern.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both setTimeInMillis and hourofday and minute.

If you want your alarm to be triggered at 4:30 just add hourofday and minute.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,4);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I could Identify the issue I was facing. I was using a TimePicker with 24 hour format. But I used SimpleDateFormat "hh:mm". What 'h' stands for is as follows "h->Hour in am/pm (1-12) ". So any alarm that I set at AM triggers correctly. When I set a time at PM since I had used 1-12 'h' format, alarm gets set for a AM time and since that time is already passed when compared to the device time the alarm/notification got triggered immediately.The right format to use was "HH:MM" where 'H' stands for     "H->Hour in day (0-23)". This resolved my issue.

Checking the TimeinMillis on online epoch time converter helped me identify this issue.Once again thanks for helping me.